# Show button inside div block using react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, button, react-state

I'm trying to show button inside div block using react. But it is showing error **Parsing error: Unexpected keyword 'this'.**

```
  <div >
            {
               {this.state.selectedTag} ?  <button onClick={() => {  this.resetTagState() }}> 
               Reset </button> : 
            }
          </div>
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to put another bracket before the keyword "this". Also, you can siplify the onClick callback, and the "else" condition is missing after the semi colon. I think the following will work for you:

```
<div>
   {
      this.state.selectedTag 
        ? <button onClick={this.resetTagState}> 
            Reset 
          </button> 
        : null
    }
</div>
```